# App crashing on starting another activity with intent and .putExtra

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to open another activity by intent and putExtra.
It used to run fine previously, but now it crashes.

```
startActivity(new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, OtpVerification.class)
                                .putExtra("user", user)
                                .putExtra("otp", verificationId));
                        finish();
```

the user here is a class object  and am receiving it in another activity

```
user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("user");
```

the app is not even going to another activty and crashes without any error message in logcat.
It only happens if i add .putExtra code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the putExtra in the following way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ForgotPassword.this, OtpVerification.class);
intent.putExtra("user", user);
intent.putExtra("otp", verificationId);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and then get the intent extras

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null)
    String data = extras.getString("keyName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user is an Object that you're trying to pass from one activity to another.
So you  can create a custom class that implements the Serializable interface.(you must be able to use Parcelable too but i don't have experience with it )

//To pass:
intent.putExtra("User", user);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("User");

Point to note: each nested class in your main custom class must have implemented the Serializable interface
eg:

```
class MainClass implements Serializable {

    public MainClass() {}

    public static class ChildClass implements Serializable {

        public ChildClass() {}
    }
}
```

Ref:[How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions, the actual problem I found was that my user object had a variable called image (String type) and had a value of length about 1,000,000 (I was storing string encoded image using base64 in it). Once i decreased the size to thousands , it worked. I don't  know why the app cannot send such large data across activities.